# Is there any way to see JavaScript default methods source-code?

Tags: javascript, specifications

Is there any way to see JavaScript default methods source-code? For example .sort() or .reverse(). I think is C code but where can I read it?

Comment: JavaScript is a specification.  There are various implementations, one of which is [Google's V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/) - you could start there.

Comment: These seem to be the definitions of [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/0b81f67b12550c118f1a94528c73e1cec01263a2/src/array.js#L857-L1140) and [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/0b81f67b12550c118f1a94528c73e1cec01263a2/src/array.js#L560-L593) in V8. They're both written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the code for [SpiderMonkey's JavaScript Array implementation](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/66a95a483d2c/js/src/jsarray.cpp) (used in Firefox), you'll want to start by looking at the `array_sort` and `array_reverse` functions. More generally, look for the `array_methods` constant; it has indices to the relevant functions.

In the code for [V8's JavaScript Array implementation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/master/src/array.js) (used in Chrome and Opera), you want to look for `ArraySort` and `ArrayReverse` functions respectively.  Look for `GlobalArray.prototype` to find an index to the other functions.

[JavaScript Core's JavaScript Array implementation](https://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/JavaScriptCore/builtins/Array.prototype.js) (used in Safari) is a bit unusual, in that `Array.prototype.sort` and its ilk are actually implemented in JavaScript. The sort function you want is simply named `sort` in this file. However, not all of the `Array.prototype` family of functions are found in that file; for example, I'm not sure where `reverse` is.

The source code for Chakra's implementation (used in IE) is not available, and I suspect that they probably never will be. The same goes for the source code for Presto's implementation (formerly used in Opera, before they switched to Blink/V8).

Comment: Finally, someone actually answers this with some resources.
and their all 404.

how would you go about inspecting the javascript source code.
I wan't to see how an implementation of any array method. 

no i understand from you'r post that there are several, any one would do. 
i would expect that if i just 
console.log(Array.prototype.forEach) i would see the js it contains. 
but i'm getting this : ƒ forEach() { [native code] }

To conclude any help observing javascript source code , tips links etc.. 
 would help

Comment: It was quite easy to find the Array source code of V8 from the above link although they are giving 404. Probably because this answer was given 5 years ago. https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/v8/+/refs/heads/master/src/array.js